# How to pass a value from a function to a class in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Goal**

I am aiming to get the `transcript` value, from the function Dictaphone and pass it into to the SearchBar class, and finally set the state `term` to `transcript`.

**Current code**

```
import React from 'react';
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition';

const Dictaphone = () => {
    const { transcript } = useSpeechRecognition()

    if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
            <p>{transcript}</p>
        </div>
    )
}



class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            term: ''
        }

        this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleTermChange(event) {
        this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchBar">
                <input onChange={this.handleTermChange} placeholder="Enter some text..." />
                <Dictaphone />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export { SearchBar };
```

**Problem**

I can render the component `<Dictaphone />` within my SearchBar. The only use of that is it renders a button and the transcript. But that's not use for me.

What I need to do is, get the `Transcript` value and set it to `this.state.term` so my input field within my SearchBar changes.

**What I have tried**

I tried creating an object within my SearchBar component and called it `handleSpeech`..

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            term: ''
        }

        this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
    }


    handleTermChange(event) {
        this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSpeech() {
        const { transcript } = useSpeechRecognition()

        if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
            return null
        }

        SpeechRecognition.startListening();

        this.setState({ term: transcript});
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchBar">
                <input onChange={this.handleTermChange} placeholder="Enter some text..." />
                <button onClick={this.handleSpeech}>Start</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Error**

But I get this error:

> React Hook "useSpeechRecognition" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
> React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error is pretty clear. You're trying to use a hook in a class component, and you can't do that.

### Option 1 - Change SearchBar to a Function Component

If this is feasible, it would be my suggested solution as the library you're using appears to be built with that in mind.

### Option 2

Communicate between Class Component <=> Function Component.

I'm basing this off your "current code".

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition';

const Dictaphone = ({ onTranscriptChange }) => {
  const { transcript } = useSpeechRecognition();

  // When `transcript` changes, invoke a function that will act as a callback to the parent (SearchBar)
  // Note of caution: this code may not work perfectly as-is. Invoking `onTranscriptChange` would cause the parent's state to change and therefore Dictaphone would re-render, potentially causing infinite re-renders. You'll need to understand the hook's behavior to mitigate appropriately.
  useEffect(() => {
    onTranscriptChange(transcript);
  }, [transcript]);
    
  if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
      <p>{transcript}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      transcript: ''
    }
    this.onTranscriptChange = this.onTranscriptChange.bind(this);
  }

  onTranscriptChange(transcript){
    this.setState({ transcript });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchBar">
        <input onChange={this.handleTermChange} placeholder="Enter some text..." />
        <Dictaphone onTranscriptChange={onTranscriptChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useSpeechRecognition` is a [React hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), which is a special type of function that only works in specific situations. You can't use hooks inside a class-based component; they only work in function-based components, or in custom hooks. See the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) for all the limitations.

Since this hook is provided by a 3rd party library, you have a couple of options. One is to rewrite your search bar component to be a function. This may take some time if you're unfamiliar with hooks.

You can also see if the `react-speech-recognition` library provides any utilities that are intended to work with class-based components.